# Remove all rows from the datatable except last one

Tags: c#, datatable

As the title says, i have a datatable, now i want to remove all the rows in the datatable except the last one. I know there can be many complex ways to do so, but i would like to know the short & efficient way to do this task.

Comment: Is there a way to determine the last one, e.g. `Id` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var lastRow = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Last();
var newDataTable = new[] {lastRow}.CopyToDataTable();
```

Advantages:

- Using `Last()` makes your intent absolutely clear and you cannot get any indexes wrong.
- The original data table is not modified.

Disadvantages:

- Bad performance (`O(n)` iteration through the list).
- Creates a new data table instead of modifying the old one in-place.
- Only the columns are kept, all other table properties (e.g. constraints) are not carried over to the new data table.

Reference:

- [`IEnumerable<DataRow>.CopyToDataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Downvoter: I appreciate a comment if you think my answer can be improved.

Comment: I haven't downvoted but LINQ is not always better imo. Creating a new DataTable if you just want to remove all but one might work, but is it easier to read? It also needs to enumerate the whole table to find the last. Also, `CopyToDataTable` creates a new table from the scratch with the same columns but with nothing else. So things like [Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.constraints%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are discarded for no reason.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thanks for your feedback. I took the liberty to copy some of it to my answer, so that posterity has a better basis for choosing the right method for their problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count -1];

dt.Rows.Clear();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: Does this work? I haven't tested it but `Clear` does a lot of things which could have side effects on the row: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,cd076a82da16d2cf,references

Comment: You had me worried. Tested and Clear() has only removed the rows and NOT columns ..etc.

Comment: Perfect solution, @TimSchmelter you have confused `DataTable.Clear` and `DataTable.Rows.Clear`

Comment: @agent5566: no  `DataTable.Rows.Clear` calls `DataTable.Clear`. You can see that [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataRowCollection.cs,fa4405fa61a15884). Dominic, i also didnt think that it clears the columns. But it might change other things that are related to the row that you have stored in the local variable. `DataTable.Clear` (`DataRowCollection.Clear`) don't know that you keep that row so the method also affects that row.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It does but it does not do the same thing. They both call the internal Clear function but with different parameters.

Comment: @Magnus: yes, but that doesn't make a great difference. The parameter `clearAll`  is only used  to know if only attached rows must be removed or also [`Detached`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) rows.

Comment: Here's the source of the method that clears the rows and it begs for serious side-effects on the row above: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/RecordManager.cs,b8e8fbdafce07ea2,references

Comment: Confirmed with following code, all values are set to `DbNull.Value` also in the last row stored locally: `DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Col1");
            dataTable.Rows.Add("Row 1");
            dataTable.Rows.Add("Row 2");
            DataRow dr = dataTable.Rows[dataTable.Rows.Count - 1];
            dataTable.Rows.Clear();
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", row.ItemArray));`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a backwards   `for`-loop + `RemoveAt`:

```
for (int i = dataTable.Rows.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    dataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dataTable = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Skip(dataTable.Rows.Count - 1).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this with a simple for loop as below

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{ 
    if(!dr.Equals(ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Last()))
    {
       ds.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(dr);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has multiple issues. You are calling `Last()` which means you have to iterate the collection every time inside to loop to get to the last row. Also removing rows from a collection that is being iterated with a for loop wont work.

Comment: loops are mostly time consuming. It is better to do it without loops.

Comment: @bogojane: you cannot do that without loops, they are either visible or hidden in framework methods. But that is not the point, as Magnus has pointed out this doesn't work because you are not allowed to modify the collection that you're enumerating in a `foreach` and it's horribly inefficient since the whole table is enumerated for every row in it.